# MediaCodec.native_configure(MediaCodec.java) crash on Samsung device

Tags: android, encode, samsung-mobile, android-mediacodec

I got many crash on Fabric report on MediaCodec configuring, 92% in 7000 users using Samsung devices like J5,J7 SM-G570.

My code works fine on my test device so I can't debug it with single step,I just want use my code to encode a steam of raw video frame. there is the report below:

```
#0. Crashed: Thread-38: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(MediaCodec.java)
       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1884)
       at com.jb.video.av.VideoEncoderCore.(VideoEncoderCore.java)
       at com.jb.video.av.VideoEditEncoderCore.(VideoEditEncoderCore.java)
       at com.jb.video.av.edit.VideoFilterDevice$RenderThread.startEncoder(VideoFilterDevice.java:567)
       at com.jb.video.av.edit.VideoFilterDevice$RenderThread.setRecordingEnabled(VideoFilterDevice.java:496)
       at com.jb.video.av.edit.VideoFilterDevice$RenderThread.run(VideoFilterDevice.java:413)

--

Fatal Exception: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
       at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(MediaCodec.java)
       at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1884)
       at com.jb.video.av.VideoEncoderCore.(VideoEncoderCore.java)
       at com.jb.video.av.VideoEditEncoderCore.(VideoEditEncoderCore.java)
       at com.jb.video.av.edit.VideoFilterDevice$RenderThread.startEncoder(VideoFilterDevice.java:567)
       at com.jb.video.av.edit.VideoFilterDevice$RenderThread.setRecordingEnabled(VideoFilterDevice.java:496)
       at com.jb.video.av.edit.VideoFilterDevice$RenderThread.run(VideoFilterDevice.java:413)
```

I log more info on this crash when it happens.
[please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUUoh.png)

My configure code is :

```
public VideoEncoderCore(int width, int height, int bitRate, Muxer muxer) throws IOException {
        mMuxer = muxer;
        mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, width, height);

//        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH, width);
//        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT, height);

        // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
        // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        if (Machine.HAS_N_MR1) {
            format.setFloat(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 0.1f);
        } else {
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "format: " + format);

        // Create a MediaCodec encoder, and configure it with our format.  Get a Surface
        // we can use for input and wrap it with a class that handles the EGL work.
        try {
            mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
            mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        } catch (Throwable tr) {
            if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (!(tr instanceof MediaCodec.CodecException)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    MediaCodec.CodecException codecException = (MediaCodec.CodecException) tr;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        Crashlytics.setInt(FabricKey.MEDIACODEC_CODEC_EXCEPTION_ERROR_CODE, codecException.getErrorCode());
                    }
                    Crashlytics.setString(FabricKey.MEDIACODEC_CODEC_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, codecException.getMessage());
                    Crashlytics.setString(FabricKey.MEDIACODEC_CODEC_EXCEPTION_DIAGNOSTIC_INFO, codecException.getDiagnosticInfo());
                    Crashlytics.setBool(FabricKey.MEDIACODEC_CODEC_EXCEPTION_IS_RECOVERABLE, codecException.isRecoverable());
                    Crashlytics.setBool(FabricKey.MEDIACODEC_CODEC_EXCEPTION_IS_TRANSIENT, codecException.isTransient());
                }

                Crashlytics.setInt(FabricKey.VIDEO_WIDTH, width);
                Crashlytics.setInt(FabricKey.VIDEO_HEIGHT, height);

                Crashlytics.log(StatisticsTools.getLastOperateIds());
                Crashlytics.logException(tr);
            } else {
                CrashHandler.getInstance().throwException(Thread.currentThread(), tr);
            }
            mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
            mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        }
        mInputSurface = mEncoder.createInputSurface();
        mEncoder.start();

        mTrackIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: what did `Log.d(TAG, "format: " + format);` print?

Comment: like the code above this line,the info set in format.

Comment: Any progress on this? Having the exact same issue.

Comment: you have to hand pick the encoder instead of auto pick,the first encoder on J7 can't encode the video